# convert .rtf tables to text (comma delimeted) then paste into an excel document

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have used a macro that runs through each cell in a word table and pastes into excel, however one of my documents has 96 pages and it will take literally 40 mins to copy it all into the spreadsheet. I have found it is much faster if the tables are converted to text (comma delimited) then saved as a .txt file, then imported into the spreadsheet, however I cannot figure out how to write a macro or vbscript to do it all at once. any ideas??

```
Private Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wddoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*DOC),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = "" Then Exit Sub

Set wddoc = GetObject(wdFileName)


With wddoc
    tableNo = wddoc.Tables.Count
    tableTot = wddoc.Tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
            tableNo = 1

    End If

    resultRow = 1

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        With .Tables(tableStart)


            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                   Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                    Cells(resultRow) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With

Set wddoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Whether screen updating turned off  in your code?

Comment: Add your code in the question itself.

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: why does this code take so long??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wddoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*DOC),*.doc", , _
            "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = "" Then Exit Sub
Set wddoc = GetObject(wdFileName)

With wddoc
    tableNo = wddoc.Tables.Count
    tableTot = wddoc.Tables.Count

    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = 1
    End If

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & tableStart & "of (" & tableTot & ") Tables"
        .Tables(tableStart).Range.Copy
        resultRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2).Row
        DoEvents
        On Error Resume Next
        Range("A" & resultRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next tableStart
End With

Set wddoc = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to run much faster and cleaner thank you. My word doc is a report generated by our system and contains 990 tables but this varies form month to month which is compared to a report from a different system that's a spreadsheet. I'm trying to automate the process which at the minute is copy and paste and a macro and formulae to manipulate and compare. the Copy and Paste is still much faster. Maybe it always will be??

Comment: Your initial code is going cell by cell of each tables.  Now the given code is going just table by table.  So it should run faster when comparing to your current code.

Comment: it has finished and cut the time down from 45 minutes to just under 10 minutes

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: Do you think that this is the fastest and most efficient way im going to be able to do this. I still reckon it quicker to open up the word document press ctrl A and then ctrl c open the spreadsheet and paste in then run macro to manipulate?

Comment: I was thinking it might be faster if a macro could to convert all tables to txt (comma delimited) and then import into excel as this is almost instant.

Comment: If you want to copy paste all word document data then it can be done in less than a second.  But the code is just copy pasting the Table data and ignoring all the paragraphs and other data which is not in table.

Comment: that is perfect as there is only tables in there, we have said until we are blue why cant the system give us a spreadsheet instead of a .rtf report but it cant happen. I would want it to ignore formatting and just paste values

Comment: added my code that I've tried to open the word document select everything and paste into excel